# Before going to sleep vs Before sleeping

Tags: prepositions

Could you say both sentences are correct and usable? As I see from Ngram Viewer, going to sleep is rarer version.

> Before going to sleep, I read for a few minutes.
>
> Before sleeping, I read for a few minutes.

Comment: You can't have constructed your NGram appropriately. The second version is [***far more common,***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Before+going+to+sleep+I%2CBefore+sleeping+I&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBefore%20going%20to%20sleep%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBefore%20sleeping%20I%3B%2Cc0) as can easily be seen from ***my*** chart. But they're both "valid".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica You meant to type *the* ***first*** *version [going to sleep] is far more common.*